# Auditing complex objects changes using JaVers

Tags: java, kotlin, javers

I blocked in auditing complex objects changes using JaVers.
I need to track SiteDto object which is complex object. My implementation design is mentioned below:
I have a entity class called site:

```
@Entity
Site 
@Id  Id: Int(PK)  
user: String  
reason: String  
siteDto: SiteDto
```

I have two services:

Service1: This service sends SiteDto to service2. The structure we get from service2 is:

```
@ValueObject
SiteDto  
name: String  
code: String  
address: String  
nodes: List<NodeDto>

@ValueObject
NodeDto:  
name: String  
code: String  
modules: Set<ModuleDto>  
devices: Set<DeviceDto>

@ValueObject
ModuleDto:   
name: String    
code: String   
configMap: Map<String, String>

@ValueObject
DeviceDto:   
name: String   
code: String    
ports: Set<PortDto>

@ValueObject
PortDto:   
name: String   
code: String   
configMap: Map<String, String>
```

Service2: - This service does following operation to track diff.

1. Receives SiteDto from Service1
2. Converts SiteDto nested objects which are having Set to List, I am converting because Set does show hash value which does not give what is changed. The structure is below.

```
@ValueObject
SiteDto  
name: String  
code: String  
address: String  
nodes: List<NodeDto>

@ValueObject
NodeDto:  
name: String  
code: String  
modules: List<ModuleDto>  
devices: List<DeviceDto>

@ValueObject
ModuleDto:   
name: String    
code: String   
configMap: Map<String, String>

@ValueObject
DeviceDto:   
name: String   
code: String    
ports: List<PortDto>

@ValueObject
PortDto:   
name: String   
code: String   
configMap: Map<String, String>
```

3. Order nested object list by alpha numeric and send SiteDto to JaVers for track diff.
4. For the first time, JaVers  will not give result because it will be in INITIAL type. it won't track diff when I query using findChanges()
5. JaVers tracks changes  of nested obects when I update nested objects list. For example: I update ModuleDto or DeviceDto or PortDto which are in the list.
6. JaVers is not giving proper diff when  I add new ModuleDto, or DeviceDto or PortDto in nested list since I does alpha numeric order.
7. JaVers is not giving proper diff when I remove old  ModuleDto, DeviceDto, PortDto from nested list because index gets change when I do alpha numeric order.

I am blocked with below issues. Could you suggest approaches to solve these issues?

6. JaVers is not giving proper diff when  I add new ModuleDto, or DeviceDto or PortDto in nested list since I does alpha numeric order.
7. JaVers is not giving proper diff when I remove old  ModuleDto, DeviceDto, PortDto from nested list because index get changed when I do alpha numeric order.